# Unix file edit for pattern substitution

Tags: sed, gawk

I have a file with repetitive patterns like below:

```
set m [ meas new $proj rajesh  ]
meas $m set_type lvf_timing
abcde erft 1213
234 456 897 00000000000000
once upon a time 

set t [ table new $m pvbt_table ]
table $t set_region_set_name lvf_clusters
table $t set_instance_condition derate_instance_condition
table $t set_corner_condition derate_corner_condition
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis CPS]
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis RPB]
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis periphery_Vt]
set a [ axis new $t process_axis]
set a [ axis new $t voltage_axis]
set a [ axis new $t temperature_axis]
set a [ axis new $t bias_axis vdda]

set t [ table new $m table ]
table $t set_equation {derate_equation pvbt_table}
table $t set_region_set_name lvf_clusters
table $t set_corner_condition derate_corner_condition
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis CPS]
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis RPB]
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis periphery_Vt]
set a [ axis new $t process_axis]
set a [ axis new $t voltage_axis]
set a [ axis new $t temperature_axis]
set a [ axis new $t bias_axis vdda]
```

I want this file to be processed so all such patterns get modified like this:

```
set m [ meas new $proj rajesh  ]
meas $m set_type lvf_timing
abcde erft 1213
234 456 897 00000000000000
once upon a time 

set t [ table new $m table ]
table $t set_region_set_name lvf_clusters
table $t set_corner_condition derate_corner_condition
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis CPS]
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis RPB]
set a [ axis new $t parameter_axis periphery_Vt]
set a [ axis new $t process_axis]
set a [ axis new $t voltage_axis]
set a [ axis new $t temperature_axis]
set a [ axis new $t bias_axis vdda]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackexchange.  Please spend a few minutes formatting this to look readable. Indenting by 4 spaces etc....

Comment: I have reformatted it. I have remove the begin/end-of-file markers and some empty lines. Can you please check this is OK @user3625743?

Comment: yes it is ok if I could get a answer for this

Comment: Also to add I need to edit the information whenever pattern set_type lvf_timing come then process the information as asked in my post

Comment: Could you please describe what's the difference between the initial file and the modified file? Or are we supposed to guess the differences?

Comment: difference b/w initial file and final file is :-

Comment: that table starting with pvbt_table  is deleted and in last table statement having pattern derate_equation pvbt_table is deleted

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
sed '/table new.*pvbt_table/, /^$/d;/pvbt_table/d' input_file
```